# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'basic.posts' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel-9

When I'm trying to add data to the categories table, it shows an error. This is because I have a database created with the name "basic" and connected with the project.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'basic.posts' doesn't exist

**category.php**

```
class Category extends Model  
{
    
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'category_name',
    ];
}
```

**CategoryController.php**

```
use App\Models\Category;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function allcat(){
        return view('admin.category.index');
    }

    public function alladd(Request $request){
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'category_name' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        
        ]);

        Category::insert([
            'category_name'=>$request->category_name,
            'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
            'created_at'=>Carbon::now()

        ]);          
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run your migrations for post model? i would suggest ```php artisan migrate:fresh```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Category::create() instead of Category::insert()

Because create() is use for single row insertion and insert() is used for multi-row insertion

And also you don't have to specify created_at timestamps, laravel model handle it

And here you are inerting single row at a time

```
Category::create([
    'category_name'=>$request->category_name,
    'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id
]);
```

Maybe it will helpful

Comment: i've tried your solution but it still doesn't work. used create instead of insert.